# How to convert shell command line into XDG .desktop Exec key?

Tags: gnome, 20.04, wine, xdg

I am using Ubuntu 20.04 x86_64 with its usual GNOME3
I tried to use Wine to install certain Cyrillic-named library software, and it created a folder "Система ИРБИС64 unicode" in my desktop, also Cyrillically-named, "Рабочий стол", full of Cyrillically-named .lnk files like "АРМ Каталогизатор.lnk"
Surely, GNOME3 refused to open these .lnk files even with Wine 5.0 and Ubuntu 20.04 (but I remember Lubuntu 20.04 was doing somewhat better in the same situation)
So after some tries I determined a command line which would open them in a single wine run:
`wine start /unix ~/"Рабочий стол/Система ИРБИС64 unicode/АРМ Каталогизатор.lnk"`
Now my question is, how to properly quote and/or escape this path to be runnable from a .desktop file
Currently I have this text inside it, and surely it does not work :

```
[Desktop Entry]
Version=1.0
Name=Каталогизатор
Exec= wine start /unix ~/"Рабочий стол/Система ИРБИС64 unicode/АРМ Каталогизатор.lnk"
Type=Application
MimeType=text/plain;
```

Any ideas on how to really make it work, to be startable right from the GUI ?
Thanks in advance for your useful help.

Comment: Change your `EXEC=` line to point to a `bash` script. Do your setup there, then call `wine`.

Comment: `~/"Рабочий стол/Система ИРБИС64 unicode/АРМ Каталогизатор.lnk"` -> `"$HOME/Рабочий стол/Система ИРБИС64 unicode/АРМ Каталогизатор.lnk"` ?